# Creating Drag n drop in html using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I hope everyone's doing good during this harsh time.
 
I'm creating an HTML template for Label printing demo.
I want to create drag and drop functionality into this page which can only be obtained through JavaScript and I am new even to HTML.
I know I this is a dumb question but I really need this functionality as it has already taken my so much time with no outcome. It would be of great help if you can tell me or guide me how to achieve this.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Label Printer</title>
<style>
    body {
        display: block;
        max-width: 29.7cm;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    div{
        width: 49.2%;
        height: 3.7125cm;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div><p>michael richardson<br>1 arbitrary road<br>coningsby ,&nbsp; Lincolnshire&nbsp;<br>IX14YY&nbsp;<br>United Kingdom<br></p></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <style media="print">@page {margin-top: 0;margin-left: 3cm;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 0;}</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use third party JS library? If yes, dragula is a really good option.  https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/

Comment: @ArpitTyagi Thanks that's really great, but is there a simple way using just small amount of js.

Comment: this may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133751/drag-and-drop-and-drag-again-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score 1):

## You need to look at [HTML drag and drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

Most important stuff is setting and accessing the data using:

[event.dataTransfer.setData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData)
and
[event.dataTransfer.getData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData)

**Example:**

I had created a small vanilla JS TaskManager project some time back that used drag and drop functionality. You can refer to the same on this [github link](https://github.com/chiragrtr/TaskManagerVanilla):

The `function drop()` will especially be useful to you. See it [here](https://github.com/chiragrtr/TaskManagerVanilla/blob/master/scripts/app.js#LC127)